# Do non voted answers lead to account suspension?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I answer for a long time to questions but no one votes (UP as well as DOWN) for my answers: will this lead to the suspension of my profile ?

Comment: As long as no one's voted *down*, there shouldn't be any negative effect (as well as the question not getting cleaned up by the Roomba, as question deletion can play a role).